# Zend_auth multiple instances

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

As ZF creates single instance of zend_auth.

But i need separate for admin and front panel of my site

So i have made a copy on zend/Auth.php and saved as zend/Autuadmin.php in library  and created sessin as zend_Authadmin and its now working fine at all places.

Is it correct way to do? 
or can it crate problem in future ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318599/multiple-instances-2-of-zend-auth ? :)

Comment: It won't work by the way as the "islogged" will return true for both when admin or user is logged - what we need is late static binding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Zend_Auth with Zend_Acl should you to create two roles with different access for each role. I control acl's using an ini file but it is quite easy to configure either way.

[Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html)

very quick example...

```
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'staff');
$acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('news'));
$acl->allow('admin', array('news', 'latest'));
```

Then to check you can use `$acl->isAllowed()`